# PyQt6: The CheckableCombobox never hides

Tags: python, macos, qwidget, qcombobox, pyqt6

I'm trying to implement a code capable to create a checkable combobox with PyQt6. My problem is that when I open the combobox for the first time, it stays opened and never hides. The functions seem to work well but I guess when it shows up for the first time it has a bug that I'm not able to fix. Please someone help me. The code I'm using is:

```
import sys
from PyQt6.QtWidgets import QApplication, QWidget, QHBoxLayout, QVBoxLayout, QPushButton, QComboBox
from PyQt6.QtCore import Qt, QEvent
from PyQt6.QtGui import QStandardItem

class CheckableComboBox(QComboBox):
    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        super(CheckableComboBox,self).__init__(parent)
        self.setEditable(True)
        #self.lineEdit().setReadOnly(True)

        self.model().dataChanged.connect(self.updateLineEditField)

    def addItems(self, items, itemList=None):
        itemList = [] if itemList is None else itemList
        for indx, text in enumerate(items):
            try:
                data = itemList[indx]
            except(IndexError):
                data = None
            self.addItem(text,data)
            

    def addItem(self,text,userData=None):
        item = QStandardItem()
        item.setText(text)
        if not userData is None:
            item.setData(userData)
        
        item.setFlags(Qt.ItemFlag.ItemIsEnabled | Qt.ItemFlag.ItemIsUserCheckable)
        item.setData(Qt.CheckState.Unchecked, Qt.ItemDataRole.CheckStateRole)
        self.model().appendRow(item)
    
    def updateLineEditField(self):
        text_container = []
        for i in range(self.model().rowCount()):
            if self.model().item(i).checkState() == Qt.CheckState.Checked:
                text_container.append(self.model().item(i).text())

        text_string=', '.join(text_container)
        self.lineEdit().setText(text_string)

class MyApp(QWidget):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        self.window_width, self.window_height = 1200,800
        self.setMinimumSize(self.window_width, self.window_height)
        self.setStyleSheet('''
            QWidget {
                font-size: 10px;
            }
        ''')

        self.layout = QVBoxLayout()
        self.setLayout(self.layout)

        combobox = CheckableComboBox()
        combobox.addItems(colors)
        self.layout.addWidget(combobox)

    def closeEvent(self, event):
        event.accept()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    colors=["Blue", "Yellow", "Green", "Red"]
    app = QApplication(sys.argv)
    myApp = MyApp()
    myApp.show()

    try:
        sys.exit(app.exec())
    except SystemExit:
        print("Closing window...")
```

I just expect it to hide when it's opened and I click the box. Just for you to know, i'm using a Mac and the python version 3.9.6 64-bit. I don't know if this is significant but just in case. I've tried functions like eventFilter but it doesn't work for me neither.

```
#def eventFilter(self, widget, event: QEvent) -> bool:
    #    if widget == self.lineEdit():
    #        if event.type() == QEvent.Type.MouseButtonPress:
    #            if self.closeOnLineEditClick:
    #                print("hide")
    #                self.hidePopup()
    #            else:
    #                print("show")
    #                self.showPopup()
    #            return True
    #        return super().eventFilter(widget, event)
#
    #    if widget == self.view().viewport():
    #        if event.type() == QEvent.Type.MouseButtonRelease:
    #            indx = self.view().indexAt(event.pos())
    #            item = self.model().item(indx.row())
#
    #            if item.checkState() == Qt.CheckState.Checked:
    #                item.setCheckState(Qt.CheckState.Unchecked)
    #            else:
    #                item.setCheckState(Qt.CheckState.Checked)
    #            return True
    #        return super().eventFilter(widget, event)
```

As @musicamante asked, here you have the complete code when I use eventFilter() but for me it fixes nothing:

```
import sys
from PyQt6.QtWidgets import QApplication, QWidget, QHBoxLayout, QVBoxLayout, QPushButton, QComboBox
from PyQt6.QtCore import Qt, QEvent
from PyQt6.QtGui import QStandardItem

class CheckableComboBox(QComboBox):
    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        super(CheckableComboBox,self).__init__(parent)
        self.setEditable(True)
        #self.lineEdit().setReadOnly(True)
        self.closeOnLineEditClick = False
        self.lineEdit().installEventFilter(self)
        self.model().dataChanged.connect(self.updateLineEditField)
    
    def eventFilter(self, widget, event: QEvent) -> bool:
        if widget == self.lineEdit():
            if event.type() == QEvent.Type.MouseButtonPress:
                if self.closeOnLineEditClick:
                    print("hide")
                    self.hidePopup()
                else:
                    print("show")
                    self.showPopup()
                    self.closeOnLineEditClick = True
                return True
        return super().eventFilter(widget, event)

    def addItems(self, items, itemList=None):
        itemList = [] if itemList is None else itemList
        for indx, text in enumerate(items):
            try:
                data = itemList[indx]
            except(IndexError):
                data = None
            self.addItem(text,data)
            

    def addItem(self,text,userData=None):
        item = QStandardItem()
        item.setText(text)
        if not userData is None:
            item.setData(userData)
        
        item.setFlags(Qt.ItemFlag.ItemIsEnabled | Qt.ItemFlag.ItemIsUserCheckable)
        item.setData(Qt.CheckState.Unchecked, Qt.ItemDataRole.CheckStateRole)
        self.model().appendRow(item)
    
    def updateLineEditField(self):
        text_container = []
        for i in range(self.model().rowCount()):
            if self.model().item(i).checkState() == Qt.CheckState.Checked:
                text_container.append(self.model().item(i).text())

        text_string=', '.join(text_container)
        self.lineEdit().setText(text_string)

class MyApp(QWidget):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        self.window_width, self.window_height = 1200,800
        self.setMinimumSize(self.window_width, self.window_height)
        self.setStyleSheet('''
            QWidget {
                font-size: 10px;
            }
        ''')

        self.layout = QVBoxLayout()
        self.setLayout(self.layout)

        combobox = CheckableComboBox()
        combobox.addItems(colors)
        self.layout.addWidget(combobox)

    def closeEvent(self, event):
        event.accept()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    colors=["Blue", "Yellow", "Green", "Red"]
    app = QApplication(sys.argv)
    myApp = MyApp()
    myApp.show()

    try:
        sys.exit(app.exec())
    except SystemExit:
        print("Closing window...")
```

Comment: Since the item flags don't include `ItemIsSelectable`, the item cannot be "clicked", and then the combo won't interact with it. You should intercept the mouse events on the view, by *installing* the event filter: it's not enough to implement `eventFilter()`, you have to call `installEventFilter()`; if you did it, then please share the [mre] that includes that attempt.

Comment: @musicamante, thanks for answering. I know I need to call installEventFilter(). Here I paste you the minimal version of the code I added when I tried it. Still the same problem. I use a couple of prints inside eventFilter() to see if it enters and it does, but self.hidePopup() does nothing.

Comment: Please don't paste code in comments. Instead, [edit] your question to update it.

Comment: The view is a popup, and will receive any mouse event (even outside its geometry), you have to install the event filter in it and then react to it. I don't exactly remember the implementation now, as the combobox popup behavior is a bit complex, but, if I recall correctly, you need to install the event filter on the viewport.

Comment: I am not able to reproduce your error.

Comment: @Alexander, what do you mean? It works for you? Thanks for trying.

Comment: @musicamante, i don't really get what you propose. Would you mind to try it? What do you mean when you say "install the event filter on the viewport"? Could you be a bit more specific please? Remember my goal is just to hide the combobox. I don't mind if it hides when I click outside the geometry of the box. My biggest problem is that when it shows the popup, the popup gets stucked like if it whas a bug and I can't use nothing more. Juts need to make it hide... "as simple as it sounds"

Comment: @JordiBujons are you implying that you are not able to close the combobox not even when clicking *anywhere* else? Because that's what both Alexander and me are not able to *reproduce*, and the only "issue" (and the expected one) is that it doesn't close when clicking *on* it. And by "install the event filter on the viewport" I exactly mean that: `self.view().viewport().installEventFilter(self)`.

Comment: @musicamante sorry again but doesn't work. I just think it's as simple as the hidePopup() function doesn't work for me. I've tried multiple things plus all your suggestions but nothing changes. Do you know any other function or whatever I could do to be able to hide the popup? I'm really upset because it has to be a silly thing but I don't know what more to try.

Comment: @JordiBujons Please answer the question. Your code should do what expected (closing the popup when clicking *outside* the view), if it doesn't it probably is a Qt bug specific to macOS.

Comment: @JordiBujons  Yes I mean that the dropdown does not remain open once it loses focus when I run your code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The code implementation exposed works. It seems the problem is caused by an specific Qt bug to macOS. Didn't find how to fix it. Just answered because the code is correct and you can use it in other operating systems. If someone someday finds out what bug I'm talking about and how to fix it, answer whenever! Thanks.

```
import sys
from PyQt6.QtWidgets import QApplication, QWidget, QHBoxLayout, QVBoxLayout, QPushButton, QComboBox
from PyQt6.QtCore import Qt, QEvent
from PyQt6.QtGui import QStandardItem

class CheckableComboBox(QComboBox):
    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        super(CheckableComboBox,self).__init__(parent)
        self.setEditable(True)
        #self.lineEdit().setReadOnly(True)
        self.closeOnLineEditClick = False
        self.lineEdit().installEventFilter(self)
        self.model().dataChanged.connect(self.updateLineEditField)
    
    def eventFilter(self, widget, event: QEvent) -> bool:
        if widget == self.lineEdit():
            if event.type() == QEvent.Type.MouseButtonPress:
                if self.closeOnLineEditClick:
                    print("hide")
                    self.hidePopup()
                else:
                    print("show")
                    self.showPopup()
                    self.closeOnLineEditClick = True
                return True
        return super().eventFilter(widget, event)

    def addItems(self, items, itemList=None):
        itemList = [] if itemList is None else itemList
        for indx, text in enumerate(items):
            try:
                data = itemList[indx]
            except(IndexError):
                data = None
            self.addItem(text,data)
            

    def addItem(self,text,userData=None):
        item = QStandardItem()
        item.setText(text)
        if not userData is None:
            item.setData(userData)
        
        item.setFlags(Qt.ItemFlag.ItemIsEnabled | Qt.ItemFlag.ItemIsUserCheckable)
        item.setData(Qt.CheckState.Unchecked, Qt.ItemDataRole.CheckStateRole)
        self.model().appendRow(item)
    
    def updateLineEditField(self):
        text_container = []
        for i in range(self.model().rowCount()):
            if self.model().item(i).checkState() == Qt.CheckState.Checked:
                text_container.append(self.model().item(i).text())

        text_string=', '.join(text_container)
        self.lineEdit().setText(text_string)

class MyApp(QWidget):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        self.window_width, self.window_height = 1200,800
        self.setMinimumSize(self.window_width, self.window_height)
        self.setStyleSheet('''
            QWidget {
                font-size: 10px;
            }
        ''')

        self.layout = QVBoxLayout()
        self.setLayout(self.layout)

        combobox = CheckableComboBox()
        combobox.addItems(colors)
        self.layout.addWidget(combobox)

    def closeEvent(self, event):
        event.accept()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    colors=["Blue", "Yellow", "Green", "Red"]
    app = QApplication(sys.argv)
    myApp = MyApp()
    myApp.show()

    try:
        sys.exit(app.exec())
    except SystemExit:
        print("Closing window...")
```

Comment: Reposting the code in the answer is not really necessary

Comment: Hi @ShadowCrafter_01, sorry if it bothered you mister. I just did it because there are different versions of the code posted and to make clear in the answer which code works (or should) as expected. Don't get angry!;)

Comment: Ok if it's not the same maybe explain what you changed to better help other users